# Android get saved network SSID

Tags: java, android, eclipse, wifi

I am trying to find a way by which I can get a list of the remembered networks' `SSID` on an Android device.

I have seen a few threads asking similar questions. However, the few questions that I have found are trying to get the known network passwords not the `SSIDS`, and the answer for the passwords is that

**1)** you can't get them without root and

**2)** they are stored in different locations depending on the device.

Is there any method that will allow me to do this?

Comment: I think you could get a list of remembered networks with http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getConfiguredNetworks()

Comment: @MariusŽilėnas That looks like what I need. If you make it answer I will accept it as correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a way to get a list of remembered networks with WifiManager.[getConfiguredNetworks()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getConfiguredNetworks())

Answer (score 0):

If your device is rooted then you get the details from XML file in your root folder.

Path -->`/data/misc/apexdata/com.android.wifi/WifiConfigStore.xml`